# Angular 7 + SSO - where to redirect to authorisation server

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to check on app load if the user is logged in and if not redirect to an authorisation server. What is the best place in an angular project to do that?
I'd like to do that before any components are visible to the user.

Comment: you can use a Guard to block all the router's paths you need to be "logged in", in this case put it on the "landing page" -> guide do [Guards](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/)

Comment: also, you may want to check [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) - it allows you to execute a piece of code before angular initializes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know an angular application is an SPA and page navigation is only about soft routings. In order to prevent an unauthorized access to any of the pages in your application you should provide a route guard (CanActivate implementation) to all your route definitions.
Im sharing a code sample below. The AccessValidator is implementing the CanActivate interface and defines required logic for redirecting unauthorized access attempts to login screen.

```
export class AccessValidatorService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    let result = true;
    if (this.shouldNavigateToLogin()) { // this check is up to you
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/' + LoginScreenComponent.ROUTE_PATH);
      result = false;
    }
    return of(result);
  }
  // ...
 }



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'example_screen',
        component: ExampleScreenComponent,
        canActivate: [AccessValidatorService]
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AccessValidatorService]
})
```

For further and in depth explanations: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

If you want to check the session validity also before each http request (service calls etc), the way you should do it is implementing an HttpInterceptor. You can follow [this](https://talhature.com/2019/04/28/angular-intercepting-http-calls/) step by step tutorial that explains how to implement an HttpInterceptor.